# I can't find my mistake in this gambler's ruin problem.

Tags: probability

I am trying to solve a problem in a game. In this game there is a card that says something like spend 1 resource and flip a coin. If the result is heads, you receive 2 of the resource back, if tails, you get back nothing.

I would like to calculate the probability that given that I only have a single resource, what is the probability that I end up with 3 resources if I repeatedly use this game action on my turn.

I believe this can be modeled using a Gambler's ruin problem by considering two players: $P_{1}$ and $P_{2}$ where $P_{1}$ has 1 resource, and $P_{2}$ has 2 resources and both players repeatedly bet 1 resource on a coinflip until the other player runs out of resources to bet with.

In this case, there seems to be a well known solution to this gamblers ruin problem which is 1/3 (c.f. [Fair Coin Flipping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin)).

I would like to try to calculate this probability by simply considering all the possible events that would leave me with three resources. I can either end up with

HH
HT
T

where if I observe T, the game ends immediately because I have no more resources to spend. In the event of HH, I also end because I had attained my goal. Finally in the event of HT, I am back down to 1 resource and I continue gambling.

I would think that because of this, the equation should be
$$P(\text{I get 2 resources}) = \frac{1}{3}  + \frac{1}{3}\left( \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3}P(\text{I get 2 resources})\right).$$

Solving for this, however,

$$P(\text{I get 2 resources}) = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{9}P(\text{I get 2 resources}) \implies  \frac{8}{9}P(\text{I get 2 resources}) = \frac{4}{9} \implies P(\text{I get 2 resources}) = \frac{1}{2}.$$

This intuitively seems incorrect, what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you from your $1$ resource, to win you could win twice in a row immediately (probability $\frac14$); or you could get win and then lose to get back to where you started (probability $\frac14$).

So your probability, $x$, of winning satisfies $x=\frac14+\frac14\cdot x$.

This leads to the correct probability of winning being $\frac13$.

Comment: Well, that is embarrassing. I spent a lot of time looking for my error and did not see the $1/4$.

Comment: @JessicaK: Well just remember that whenever you want **expected** value you need to **weight** the values of the possible outcomes by how often they are **expected**. But anyway carelessness can't be helped sometimes so don't worry too much about it.